# Gerar combinações de 5 digitos

Tags: php

Como faço para gerar combinações em php de 5 dígitos que vai de 0 a 9?

Nessa mesma, no futuro queira adicionar letra, como deve ser feito?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode colocar esse código o seguinte:

```
    function gerarnumeros($length = 10) {
       return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='0123456789', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);
    }
```

*Caso queira adicionar letras, é só colocar letras no código acima.

Dai você coloca `gerarnumeros(5);` no seu código.

*resposta [baseada neste link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator)*

Comment: Obrigado. O que seria esse **10** no `($length = 10)`

Comment: @Tiago não, seria como ele colocou no exemplo mesmo. `gerarnumeros(5)` para gerar combinações com 5 digitos. Se quer com 7 digitos, coloque `gerarnumeros(7)`

Comment: @acklay Eu entendi, mas gostaria de saber do que se trata `($length = 10)`

Comment: @Tiago isso quer dizer que se você não colocar um tamanho, deixar a função sem parâmetro, ele irá pegar o valor atribuído como default. Faça o teste usando apenas: `gerarnumeros()`

Answer (score 4):

Uma forma para gerar uma combinação com letras e números, seria usando a função [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shuffle.php) para misturar os elementos de um *array* e o `foreach` pegando somente a quantidade de caracteres passados como parâmetro:

```
function gerarCombinacao($tam){
    // cria um vetor com os caracteres minúsculos, maiúsculos e números
    $seed = str_split('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789');
    // mistura os elementos do array
    shuffle($seed); 
    $rand = '';
    // pega somente a quantidade de caracteres passados 
    // na variável $tam como parâmetro
    foreach (array_rand($seed, $tam) as $k) $rand .= $seed[$k];    
    // retorna a combinação
    return $rand;
 }
```

Para usar, basta passar como parâmetro a quantidade de cobinações:

```
 print gerarCombinacao(5);
```

Veja [funcionando no IDEONE](http://ideone.com/hoTI4B).

Answer (score 1):

Se for apenas número também poderia utilizar, sem necessidade de loop (*embora pessoalmente acredite que o loop, usado na resposta do [@bfavaretto♦](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/225835/15089) seja melhor*):

```
echo sprintf('%05d', random_int(0, ((10 ** 5) - 1)));
```

[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8dedfcc379157b6e2feb0cc475a4f15850509683)

Isso iria fazer gerar de `0` até `99999`, que é o valor máximo que pode ser gerado com 5 números.

Se quiser aumentar o número poderia trocar o `5` por quanto quiser, se quiser utilizar alguma função um pouco mais legivel:

```
function gerar_numero($tamanho)
{
    return str_pad(random_int(0, str_repeat(9, $tamanho)), $tamanho, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```